# Is there anything I can do to improve boot speed?

Tags: archlinux, performance, boot

I love my Pi, but it takes a considerable time to boot. If I want to use it as a Media Centre, it's quite important that it powers up quickly.

Are there any steps I can take to improve boot performance?

Comment: Leave it on? :P

Comment: That was my initial response, but [other](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-it-suitable-for-running-continuously-24-7) [questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/251/how-can-i-determine-when-an-sd-card-needs-replacement) have made me think twice about doing this.

Comment: SD cards life is largely dependant on writes. Are they affected by leaving them on?

Comment: I have no idea how many disk writes an install performs while idle...

Comment: Buy a faster SD card :-)

Comment: External HDD or SSD as the root partition?

Comment: @Haskeller Since that would have to be via USB I doubt it would improve performance.

Comment: My Class 10 SD card has ~7MB/s while my external HDD has ~30MB/s

Comment: @Haskeller Yes, sorry. I was thinking about USB 1.1 for some reason, which wouldn't have been much faster at all.

Comment: Sleep mode ftw?

Comment: There's a sleep mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Certain things can be disabled that improve boot up speed - swap for instance (my Pi takes ages to activate it.)

However, SD card reads are comparatively slow, and the device itself isn't all that fast - I don't think there's a magic bullet to make it boot up that much faster than by default.

I know it's something you've considered already, but personally I would just leave it on. The two main reasons for not doing so appear to be stability (which could be solved by a cron job reboot every so often if it proves to be an issue at all) and SD card wear. While I don't have any figures on how quickly the latter will take place, there's things you can do to mitigate it (disabling swap) and for the price of SD cards, I'd be tempted to just see what happens. If it dies relatively quickly, you can revisit it and you've not thrown away that much. If it lasts for a couple of years or more (which I highly suspect may well be the case, though I have no benchmarks for that) I think £10 every few years is a rather low maintenance cost in the grand scheme of things.

As mentioned already the main thing that kills SD cards is lots of writes, and I can't think of anything that would really be doing that (or should be doing that) when the Pi is sitting idle.

Comment: I don't think stability is a problem - Linux machines are known to run for many months, often years, without rebooting.  As for writes, there are a lot of log files in `/var/log` that will be regularly updated.  The solution would be to disable logging, or mount `/var/log` as tmpfs (which uses system memory as temporary storage.)

Comment: What about battery powered applications, where leaving it on is a waste of resources?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to switch to a whole new init system, I've found that using [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) allows the system to boot up considerably quicker, although I haven't done any benchmarks to give any real numbers.

Comment: Arch already uses systemd I believe.

Comment: I had to manually install it and switch to it explicitly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just installed the proposed Arch version, it has systemd enabled by default. (For future reference, today's January 14th 2013).

Answer (score 0):

1. Leave it on (as berry120 said:)
2. Make a bootchart to see what takes time, then eliminate where possible
3. replace slow software with smaller/faster options
4. maybe try readahead (or try disabling readahead if it was already on and doing harm)

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:
Strip SystemV at /etc/rc.sysinit

- Remove RAID
- Remove LVM(depends)
- Remove BTRFS detection

or Use systemd

Parallel load the programs

Compile the [kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) with hardfloat

If parts of your root partition are static use [Squashfs](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) noted in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Maximizing_Performance#Compressing_.2Fusr)

E.g /usr /bin /sbin .. etc..

/etc/fstab

```
noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,data=writeback
```

External SSD and HDD for the root partition

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how to make sections of the filesystem `squashfs`? That would make this answer much more useful, and is also the only thing I'm not already doing.