# Would systemd readahead be beneficial to a SD card?

Tags: boot

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Readahead

```
systemctl enable systemd-readahead-collect.service systemd-readahead-replay.service
```

Could it boost the boot speed of the Raspberry Pi? Is the boot speed noticeable?
Will it affect the SD card in any way?

Comment: There is a good answer regarding the use of readahead found [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1057/40). In a nutshell, it recommends it not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In this thread](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=1956), people say that `readahead` increases performance of sequential reads from the SD card.

This [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/) also suggests that `readahead` is a key feature to boost boot times, even on very fast media such as SSDs. This is because the normal boot sequence has a lot of "holes" (in term of CPU usage) waiting for things to be ready (just think at `udev` populating `/dev` directory, etc.). These "holes" can be used by `readahead` to prefetch disk sectors that will be used later in the boot sequence, thus skipping blocking I/O requests.

Answer (score 3):

I would hazard a *no* on this. SD cards have low transfer rates and yet reasonable seek times. Read ahead works best when finding data on a medium with a high transfer rate but a slow seek time. Reading more than you absolutely have to from an SD card will always be pretty slow.