# What can I remove from raspbian to boot faster?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I want to use my raspberry in an embedded application.

I am using already minibian and destroyed (accidentally) the network manager.
This got me downto a boot time of 13s.

I need : Gpio pin access, audio out, Python, moc (music on console)

Ideas what and how I can remove from the system? (Example: SSH, user login, networking) It should decrease boot time.

**See Answers: We got it down to ~7 seconds.**

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/how-can-i-improve-boot-time-on-raspbian?rq=1

Comment: check the output of `dmesg` - uninstall anything you think you don't need

Comment: Related: DietPi and Jessie Lite have a boot time of about 15 s, see: http://i.imgur.com/If3sFl4.png

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to know what's responsible for boot time with systemd, run
`systemd-analyze blame` or `systemd-analyze critical-chain`
and then decide whether there are things you can live without and/or research the items which you think may be sped up.

Comment: Didn't know that thing existed at all. Nice one!

Comment: It is cool, but beware it has an interesting definition of "running".  For example, `blame` makes no mention of `ssh.service` on a fresh jessie install, even though `systemctl status ssh` refers to it as "loaded active running".  So you might want to also check the more inclusive `systemctl list-units`.

Comment: When should I run it? after the boot finishes, or put it in /etc/rc.local or a similar file? When running it after the boot finishes for some reason it says Bootup has not finished yet (weird huh?).

Answer (score 12):

Things I did so far:

- Remove networking (boot stalled until network is connected): ~5sec

  `update-rc.d -f networking remove`

  Reenable temporary with:

  `/etc/init.d/networking start && ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`
- Removed boot messages during boot (yes printing messages eats time): ~2s

  Just add a `quiet` to /boot/cmdline.txt
- Following this [guide](https://hallard.me/raspberry-pi-read-only/) shaved also a few seconds of: ~2s

  The performance got especially better after moving to `busybox` and removing `ntp`.
  Additionally it is useful for me that the system is read only now, because I get better sd card lifetime on the one hand and no corruption because of power loss on the other hand.
- **Ugly, don't do this.** (Or do it and blame yourself) Then I removed logging facilities: ~0.5s

  `update-rc.d -f busybox-syslogd remove; update-rc.d -f busybox-klogd remove`

  (Yes I just added it....)

I am currently down to 6.934 (1.226+5.708) seconds. (6.78 seconds without hdmi plugged in)

I tried my luck with `systemd-readahead` but this added almost one second to my boot time.