# How to avoid fsck at boot timing out

Tags: systemd, fsck

If the raspberry pi doesn't shut down cleanly, it forces a `fsck` at boot.  My filesystem is on a 64GB micro SD card and it takes quite a while to `fsck`. Before the `fsck` finishes, a couple of services timeout, so it ends up in emergency mode. This happens, even though the filesystem is fine.

This is a problem for me because I want this raspberry pi to run unattended and headless.  If it goes into emergency mode after a power outage it'll just disappear from the network and I won't be able to do anything about it until I can physically access it again. Raspbian shouldn't require that much care and attention.

I can reproduce the problem by forcing it to check the filesystem with:

```
sudo tune2fs -c 10 -C 15 /dev/mmcblk0p2.
```

**NOTE:** If you do this, it causes the pi to always go to emergency mode. So make sure you can log in to the console to switch it back again with

```
sudo tune2fs -c -1
```

Googling the problem, it seems that some other people have run into this too. See [RPI boots into emergency mode, how do I remove it?](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3zop09/rpi_boots_into_emergency_mode_how_do_i_remove_it/).

It's also been suggested that the [fsck is unnecessary](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213548).

But since this is my root filesystem I can't remove it from `/etc/fstab`.  I tried adding `noauto,x-systemd.automount` to the options in `/etc/fstab`, but it didn't change anything.

Does anyone have a recipe for any of these?

- lengthening the timeout
- preventing an fsck on startup
- preventing the filesystem being marked as dirty on unexpected power loss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not want to take the risk of corrupting your SD Card by disabling `fsck` on startup you can use your first suggestion: "*lengthening the timeout*" on starting services. With *systemd* you can easily change `DefaultTimeoutStartSec` in

```
/etc/systemd/system.conf
```

In `man systemd.service` you will find:

> **TimeoutStartSec=** Configures the time to wait for start-up. If a daemon service does not signal start-up completion within the configured time, the service will be considered failed and will be shut down again. Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Pass "infinity" to disable the timeout logic. Defaults to DefaultTimeoutStartSec= from the manager configuration file, except when Type=oneshot is used, in which case the timeout is disabled by default (see systemd-system.conf(5)).

Comment: I'm glad you weighed in on this one. I learn more about `systemd` each time I read one of your answers :) +!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted.  I extended the timeout to "5min" and it boots cleanly now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Like many other activities, booting is now controlled by `systemd` processes. I suspect that there is a way to give `fsck` additional time to complete, but I don't know enough about that to advise. However, `systemd` still depends on `/etc/fstab` for its instructions. One way to prevent an `fsck` timeout is simply to **disable `fsck`** during boot. Without rendering any opinion on the wisdom of this (see note), following is a **"recipe for preventing `fsck` on startup"**:

Edit `/etc/fstab` as follows:

FROM:

```
PARTUUID=whatever  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

TO:

```
PARTUUID=whatever  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       0
```

Note:
@Ingo makes a valid point in his comment below this answer. I can't comment on the negative opinions wrt `systemd` rendered by others in the thread you referenced, nor will I speculate on the "cost" of a failure of your root filesystem that could have been avoided by running `fsck`. I feel these are matters of circumstance and opinion, and since this is your data, only your opinion is valid.

That said, there is [at least one answer here in RPi SE that presents a convincing argument that running `fsck` ***on an SD card*** is a waste of time](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88089/83790) because it's just not effective.

If data loss matters to you, you should put a backup system in place. And if you inhibit `fsck` on boot as shown here, you still have the option to take your RPi offline periodically to run `fsck` on the SD card. If, on the other hand, booting quickly is a priority, and your usage is such that the data and files on your system are easily replaced, perhaps it's not worth the bother. Again, as the data owner, these are choices only you are qualified to make.

Comment: Huh.. you should really spend a few words about this setting. I could make the SD Card complete unreadable after a time without fixing file system errors. Anyway +1

Comment: @Ingo: You're right - I should have; my disclaimer is rather [gutless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gutless) :)

Comment: Upvote to this one because it is also a solution in my case, where data loss is fine but failing to boot up properly is a pain.  I tested it and it works.  In the usual case there's nothing wrong with the filesystem anyway.  Even if there is corruption there's at least a good chance it'll boot up until I can reach the thing for maintenance.  The other solution is cleaner, but disabling the fsck entirely could be useful for some people e.g. if reducing outage length is important.