# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B won't boot but SD Card and board are fine

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, boot-issues

My RPi has worked fine for a while but recently it stopped booting, only the red LED is on while the green ACT one is not.
I'm sure board is fine because I put another SD Card from another RPi and it works just fine.

I'm positive the card is fine because I flashed it with a brand new RPi image and that works too.

At this point I don't want to lose all my settings so I connected
the card to my laptop and created an image using dd. I formatted the card and re-flashed it with with my `.img` file but without success.

I did a `fsck` and found a bad magic number problem a tried a procedure similar to this, [How Do I Fix a "Bad magic number in super-block" error?](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/20599/how-do-i-fix-a-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-error), but did not work either.

Is there any other way I could spot where the problem lies?

From `fdisk`:

```
Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         8192   137215   129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       137216 30318591 30181376 14,4G 83 Linux
```

Output of `fsck`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
   
     e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

 or

    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Here's the output of `dosfsck` on the boot partition:

```
    sudo dosfsck /dev/sdb1
    fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
    0x25: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.

1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
?
```

Comment: *"I'm positive the card is fine because I flashed it with a brand new Rpi image and that works too"* -> That does not really positively prove the card is fine.  It would have been good if you had included more details about the procedure you tried, particularly what "did not work" means.  Did the fsck throw errors, or did it not but then on reboot the problem was the same?  If it threw errors, what were they?

Comment: *"I formatted the card and reflashed it with with my .img file"* -> This is a superstitious exercise (albeit common enough, it seems).  The image that's written to the SD card completely overwrites any formatting that was on the card.  Ie., it does not matter at all what was on the card before you wrote an image to it, and formatting it or otherwise modifying the content first makes no difference.

Comment: My apologies if my question wasn't clear enough. I'm still not convinced the card is not fine. I flashed it (using dd) with a brand new raspbian image and it booted and I logged it so it's not a hardware problem I assume.

Comment: if pi is fine because a card from another pi works, try replicating the working image.  if that works (check the config files on the boot sector) or does not (bad sd?), figure out why.

Comment: I ran out of time so since I could mount the sd card I backed up the main settings on another location by simply doing some rsync and reflashed the *** same *** sdcard with a newly downloaded image and restore my old settings. Everything worked out fine, thanks to everyone who contributed to this, good learning experience on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I read through your question rather quickly, but from my reading I'd have to guess that there **was** a problem with your SD card, and re-flashing it has corrected whatever the problem was.

I don't know how to fix your *magic number fault*. As a guess, a file on your `/boot` drive was deleted or corrupted. Is the file `/boot/bootcode.bin` still on the SD card? ([Ref boot sequence](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10595/83790)). You *may* be able to compare the .img file you created with your current working image file, but that's a guess; [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+repair+a+magic+number+fault&atb=v278-1&ia=web) may provide other clues.

I'm only answering here in an effort to offer an idea for data recovery, and to suggest you add a couple of things to your `lessons learned` from this episode.

##### Lessons to be learned:

1. Always have a good, reliable backup ***before*** disaster strikes. Here's [my preferred backup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790) solution FWIW.
2. Don't use `dd` - there are more reliable solutions, and there are faster solutions that don't copy gigabytes of unused space on your SD card.
3. Always have a spare SD card.

##### Data recovery:

You may be able to recover most or all of your files from the *un-bootable* SD card - or its `dd`-created image. This ***assumes*** your `dd`-created image is usable, you can write it to a USB card, and can `mount` it from your now-running system. If you're unfamiliar, this overview may help:

```bsh
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/recovery/boot
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/recovery/root 
# you can manually `mount` the two filesystems, or add them to `/etc/fstab`
```

```
# in /etc/fstab: 

# mount / & /boot partitions for SD card from another system - a conventional fstab config:
# NOTE: these UUIDs for RPi 3B+ buster uSD card
UUID=592B-C92C /mnt/sdpi/boot vfat ro,user,nofail 0 0
UUID=706944a6-7d0f-4a45-9f8c-7fb07375e9f7 /mnt/sdpi/root ext4 ro,user,nofail 0 0
```

With all of that done, you can now mount your *old* SD card via USB:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -av
```

I'd like to take this opportunity to ***reinforce*** the utility of having spare SD card(s). Instead of having to write your `dd-copied-image` to a thumb drive, you could use something like this, and simply pop it in your RPi's USB drive - so much easier!

[image: SD-USB-Adapter]

Once mounted, you'll be able to assess what you've got to work with. If it looks good, you can `cp` or `rsync` your files from the *old* to the *new* SD card.

##### Addendum:

The OP has asked about diagnostics on the SD card. I'm not sure diagnostics will be of much use under the circumstances, but everyone should be aware of what is available. Many of the details are covered in other Q&A here, so I'll try to link those & summarize briefly:

1. Keeping up with `fsck`: By default, `fsck` is run each time your system boots, and a log entry is made. [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116571/83790) has some information that may help you track what's been going on. ***For a live system*** the last item in this answer will probably yield the most information: `journalctl -u systemd-fsck*`. However - if you can `mount` & access the filesystem on your *failed/corrupted* SD card, you will have to review the *"native"* logs at `var/log/syslog` (`zgrep` is your friend for the compressed logs).
2. [This Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135876/is-my-sd-card-defective/135877#135877) may be more interesting and informative. In particular the *scathing comments* from goldilocks < :) LOL > finally registered on me wrt filesystem vs media/device. After all of the dust settled, one *possibly predictive* log entry to watch for is this: `print_req_error` (ref OP's Q). One way to get at that is this command: `journalctl -u print_req_error | less`. On my RPi 4's SanDisk SD card (the oldest I have), this is the output I see:

> -- Logs begin at Thu 2019-02-14 04:11:59 CST, end at Tue 2022-05-03 20:10:43 CDT. --
> -- No entries --

```
     Consequently, I'm feeling good so far.
```

3. If you want to run `fsck` on your *failed/corrupted* SD card, you may also do that, but [I am in the camp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88089/83790) that believes that is largely a waste of time and effort. Here's [a *step-by-step* for running `fsck`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119811/83790)
4. I'll close with [this Q&A on the `/lost+found` folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18157/286615) from the U&L SE. I *suspect* this is not relevant to your case because on RPi, the files being used to boot are not in your root `ext4` filesystem, but rather in your FAT32 `/boot` filesystem - which has no `/lost+found` folder.

Comment: Since I can mount the sdcard on my laptop is there any diagnostic I can still do? The solution looks pretty straightforward to me reflashing it like I did and copy settings and files back but I'd like to give it a try before that process. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of image-backup, great tool.

Comment: @ThomasUkenagashi: `"is there any diagnostic I can still do?"` Yes - but first, I would like you to [read this short piece from the `Help` section](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), and do whatever you think best.

Comment: @ThomasUkenagashi: I've edited my answer in an effort to address your Q re diagnostics.